# Nesting immediately invoked functions Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a program which stores images and their names in an array. The names are displayed in a list, the corresponding image is displayed on click
   I also want to count the clicks on the image once it is displayed. At a later point per image, right now I am just trying to count total clicks.

The code below does not display the clicks in the Console, I do not get any error.
    Is it not possible to nest two immediately invoked functions like this?

```
for (var i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {

 //Building the list . Creating a list item and  textnode. The textnode  reads out the catnames. Append the textnode to the list. Append all of it to the catlist in the HTML
    var catitem = document.createElement("LI");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(cats[i].id);
    catitem.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("catlist").appendChild(catitem);

    //Adding the catname to the div
    var currentcat = cats[i].id;
    var currentimage = cats[i].img;

    catitem.addEventListener('click', (function(currentimage_copy) {

        return function() {
            var clicks = 0;

            var x = document.createElement("IMG");
            x.setAttribute("src", currentimage_copy);
            var item = document.getElementById("catimage");
            var y = document.getElementById("catimage").childNodes[0];
            item.replaceChild(x, y);

            x.setAttribute("onclick", (function countClicks(clickscopy) {
                return function countClicks() {
                    clicks++;
                    console.log(clickscopy);
                };
            })(clicks));
```

Here is the full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<title>||Cats||</title>
</head>

<body>

 <h1>This is the list of cats<h1>
 <h2>Click the cat to see an image of the cat</h2>
 <ul id="catlist">
 </ul>

<div id="catimage">
</div>

 <div id="catname"></div>

 <div id="current"></div>
<script>
document.body.onload = addElement;

function addElement() {


var cats = [{
        img: "cat.jpg",
        id: "cleo"
    },

    {
        img: "shimi.png",
        id: "shimi"
    },

    {
        img: "miezi.png",
        id: "miezi"

    },
    {
        img: "tom.jpg",
        id: "tom"
    },

    {
        img: "chrissie.jpg",
        id: "chrissie"
    }
];




for (var i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {

    //Building the list . Creating a list item and  textnode. The textnode      reads out the catnames. Append the textnode to the list. Append all of it to the catlist in the HTML
    var catitem = document.createElement("LI");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(cats[i].id);
    catitem.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("catlist").appendChild(catitem);

    //Adding the catname to the div
    var currentcat = cats[i].id;
    var currentimage = cats[i].img;

    catitem.addEventListener('click', (function(currentimage_copy) {

        return function() {
            var clicks = 0;

            var x = document.createElement("IMG");
            x.setAttribute("src", currentimage_copy);
            var item = document.getElementById("catimage");
            var y = document.getElementById("catimage").childNodes[0];

            item.replaceChild(x, y);

            x.setAttribute("onclick", (function countClicks(clickscopy) {
                return function countClicks() {
                    clicks++;
                    console.log(clickscopy);
                };
            })(clicks));


        };

    })(currentimage));


}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is cats ? Share that array too...Also share the HTML..

Comment: Here is the full code

Comment: Why would you use `addEventListener('click', …)` first and then `setAttribute('onClick', …)`? Use the proper (first) method. And yes, it's certainly possible to nest IIFEs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use `addEventListener` instead of `setAttribute`

Try this:

```js
var cats = [{
  id: 1,
  img: 'https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png'
}, {
  id: 2,
  img: 'https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'
}, ]
for (var i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {

  //Building the list . Creating a list item and  textnode. The textnode  reads out the catnames. Append the textnode to the list. Append all of it to the catlist in the HTML
  var catitem = document.createElement("LI");
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(cats[i].id);
  catitem.appendChild(textnode);
  document.getElementById("catlist").appendChild(catitem);

  //Adding the catname to the div
  var currentcat = cats[i].id;
  var currentimage = cats[i].img;

  catitem.addEventListener('click', (function(currentimage_copy) {
    return function() {
      var clicks = 0;
      var x = document.createElement("IMG");
      x.setAttribute("src", currentimage_copy);
      var item = document.getElementById("catimage");
      var y = document.getElementById("catimage").childNodes[0];
      item.replaceChild(x, y);

      x.addEventListener("click", (function countClicks(clickscopy) {
        return function countClicks() {
          clickscopy++;
          console.log(clickscopy);
        };
      })(clicks));
    }
  })(currentimage))
}
```

```html
<ul id='catlist'></ul>

<div id='catimage'>
  <img src="" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: I replaced addEventListener for setAttributes                x.addEventListener("onclick", (function countClicks(clickscopy) {
                   Clicks do not get counted

Comment: Click on the __Run code snippet__ and test..If it works, Compare your code with provided code in answer..